# Create resource dictionary with C# in .NET MAUI

Tags: c#, maui, resourcedictionary

I am trying to create C# utilities for MAUI's initial setup to make sure the setup process isn't scattered across 5 files. For this, I need to convert the following into C# code:

```xml
<ResourceDictionary>
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Styles/Colors.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Styles/Styles.xaml" />
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

So far I have tried two ways:

```cs
var converter = new ResourceDictionary.RDSourceTypeConverter();

try
{
    var c = converter.ConvertFromString(resourcepath);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // thrown not implemented exception
}

resourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries.Add(new()
{
    Source = new Uri(resourcepath, UriKind.Relative) // throws exception saying I need to use XAML
});
```

Is there any other way to create resource dictionaries that doesn't impact performance?

Comment: One important thing to consider: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/resource-dictionaries?view=net-maui-7.0#merge-resource-dictionaries

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely instantiate a `ResourceDictionary` and add it dynamically to the `MergedDictionaries` of the app's resources.

However, that usually works somewhere along these lines (taken and modified from the **App.xaml.cs** file in one of my own repos):

```cs
if (Current?.Resources.MergedDictionaries is not { } mergedDictionaries) 
{ 
    return; 
} 
  
mergedDictionaries.Clear(); 
mergedDictionaries.Add(new global::Resources.Styles.Colors());
mergedDictionaries.Add(new global::Resources.Styles.Styles());
```

Note that those resource dictionaries are compiled. You cannot just reference them as a path. I don't know whether this is actually faster than the default way or not, though.

**Update**

For this to work, you'll need to update the `Colors.xaml` and `Styles.xaml` XAML-only resource dictionaries and give them a class name using the `x:Class` attribute:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<?xaml-comp compile="true" ?>
<ResourceDictionary 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    x:Class="Resources.Styles.Colors">

</ResourceDictionary>
```

Then you can instantiate them using `new global::Resources.Styles.Colors()` and `new global::Resources.Styles.Styles()`.

**Update 2**

It probably also works if you provide the `x:Name` of the `ResourceDictionary` a fully qualified name like `MyProject.Resources.Styles.Colors` and then instantiate it without the `global::`, like so:

```cs
mergedDictionaries.Add(new Resources.Styles.Colors());
```

**Further Reading**

The official documentation also shows how to add resource dictionaries dynamically (for theming an app, but the principle is the same): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/theming?view=net-maui-7.0#load-a-theme-at-runtime

Comment: I don't find `Styles` under `Resources`. What namespace is `Resources` from?

Comment: The namespace might be different, although that's the default namespace for the resource dictionaries that come with the MAUI template. Did you move those files somewhere else? What's Intellisense suggesting?

Comment: You may need to add a code behind file for the resource dictionary in order for this approach to work.  I've used resources like that already before, but never with XAML-only dictionaries.

Comment: I am inside the "Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Application" constructor. I only see a property called Resources and no such namespaces

Comment: Why are you in that constructor? Please show more code. Like I already wrote, I've based my answer on the default location of the `Colors.xaml` and `Styles.xaml` files. And what are you trying to achieve anyway?

Comment: I was trying to move the default code from App.xaml into a pure C#. Yes, I get your code is based on the default locations, but `Resources.Styles.` doesn't compile for me. Not sure if it is the MAUI version.
here is my source code for this https://github.com/neville-nazerane/Socially/blob/mobile_poc2/src/Socially.MobileApp/Utils/FluentAppHelper.cs

Comment: @NevilleNazerane I've updated my answer, it was missing an important piece. You need to add the `x:Class` attribute to the XAML to give it a class name that can be referenced from C# code. See above

Comment: this doesn't work

Comment: @axa That's not a helpful comment. What doesn't work for you? I've done this many times before and it works. Note how I took some of the code from a repo of mine.

Answer (score 0):

For those looking to use Resource Dictionaries' in MAUI WITHOUT xaml pages (just C#), this is how I got it to work.

NOTE: The only xaml pages in my project are the default Resources\Styles\Styles.xaml and Resources\Styles\Colors.xaml

Create a code-behind file for the xaml resource page.

```
namespace MyApp.Resources.Styles;

public partial class Styles : ResourceDictionary
{
    public Styles()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

then modify the xaml from

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<?xaml-comp compile="true" ?> <-- REMOVE THIS SO THE CODE-BEHIND FILE WILL COMPLIE
<ResourceDictionary 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml">
```

to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<ResourceDictionary 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    x:Class="MyApp.Resources.Styles.Styles"> <-- ADD FULLY QUALIFIED CLASS NAME
```

then add in the App.cs constructor (as Julian suggested)

```
if (Application.Current?.Resources.MergedDictionaries is not { } mergedDictionaries) 
{ 
    return; 
} 
  
mergedDictionaries.Clear(); 
mergedDictionaries.Add(new Resources.Styles.Colors());
mergedDictionaries.Add(new Resources.Styles.Styles());
```

To use in a C# page constructor (EX: MainPage.cs)

```
Application.Current.Resources.TryGetValue("BtnStyle", out object btnStyle);
```

then to a control

```
new Button 
    {
      Text = "Click Me",
      Style = (Style)btnStyle,
    }
```

Remember to add a x:Key to any styles defined in the xaml resource definitions.
file Styles.xaml

```
    <Style x:Key="BtnStyle" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource White}, Dark={StaticResource Primary}}" />
        
 ************* OMITTED SETTERS ***************
        
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```